GROUP BY is not working with multiple Case Statements and a Left Join
I have two tables I am trying to write a GROUP BY clause with multiple CASE statements so that the data will be grouped into one row for each client instead of multiple rows for each client.
Here is a quick glance of the tblClient and tblServices table:


These are my current results:

Here are my desired results:

I wrote two queries and the both give me the current results and not my desired results:
SELECT 
    c.ClientID, CreateDate,
    MAX (CASE WHEN c.ServiceID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ‘Kitchen’,
    MAX (CASE WHEN c.ServiceID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ‘Living Room’,
    MAX (CASE WHEN c.ServiceID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ‘Dining Room’,
    MAX (CASE WHEN c.ServiceID = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ‘Family Room’
FROM 
    tblClient c 
LEFT JOIN 
    s.tblServices s ON s.ServiceID = s.ServiceID
GROUP BY
    c.ClientID, CreateDate, c.ServiceID 

SELECT 
    c.ClientID, CreateDate,
    (CASE WHEN c.ServiceID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ‘Kitchen’,
    (CASE WHEN c.ServiceID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ‘Living Room’,
    (CASE WHEN c.ServiceID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ‘Dining Room’,
    (CASE WHEN c.ServiceID = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ‘Family Room’
FROM 
    tblClient c 
LEFT JOIN 
    s.tblServices s ON s.ServiceID = s.ServiceID
GROUP BY
    c.ClientID, CreateDate, 
    CASE WHEN c.ServiceID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    CASE WHEN c.ServiceID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
    CASE WHEN c.ServiceID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    CASE WHEN c.ServiceID = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

I am using SQL Server.

You first query may work if you remove c.ServiceID from the group by.  Assuming you want a true/false type of result and not a count.

Which dbms are you using? The above queries are both returning syntax error according to ANSI/SQL.

BTW, those are case expressions.

GROUP BY c.ClientID, CreateDate, c.ServiceID means you want one result row per c.ClientID, CreateDate and c.ServiceID. But you don't. It seems you want one result row per c.ClientID and CreateDate, so why do you have the c.ServiceID in the GROUP BY?

Why do you even LEFT JOIN tblClient? I can't find any references to any of its columns.

I suppose the typographic quotes (‘) are supposed to be double quotes (") in order to create aliases that can contain blanks?

Please add a tag for the specific RDBMS you're using: MySQL, MariaDB, SQL-Server, Oracle, etc.

On a side note: tblClient sounds like a bad name for a table that does not contain one row per client (ClientID). This looks more like a client_service bridge/junction table that is meant to link rows from the service table with some client table.

Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots (how to format code in posts). Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Why don't you use JSON_ARRAYAGG() and JSON_OBJECTAGG()?

Summary from the request comments: If you want one result row per client and date, then group by client and date.
SELECT 
    c.clientid, c.createdate,
    MAX (CASE WHEN c.serviceid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Kitchen",
    MAX (CASE WHEN c.serviceid = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Living Room",
    MAX (CASE WHEN c.serviceid = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Dining Room",
    MAX (CASE WHEN c.serviceid = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Family Room"
FROM tblclient c 
GROUP BY c.clientid, c.createdate
ORDER BY c.clientid, c.createdate;

If you rather want one result row per clientid only, then GROUP BY c.clientid and either select MIN(c.createdate) or MAX(c.createdate) or no date at all.
